# How to print a cursor in a PL/SQL block?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, ref-cursor

I can't seem to print cursor, what am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE
  LEADEMAIL VARCHAR2(200);
  CLIENTID NUMBER;
  v_Return ON24MASTER.WEBCAST_REPORTS.ResultSetCursor;
BEGIN
  LEADEMAIL := 'nunyo@business.com';
  CLIENTID := 22921;

  v_Return := WEBCAST_REPORTS.LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    LEADEMAIL => LEADEMAIL,
    CLIENTID => CLIENTID
  );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Return = ' || v_Return);
--    :v_Return := v_Return;

END;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 14, column 26:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
ORA-06550: line 14, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Most of the code was taken directly from running the function from SQL developer.

This is the package function:

```
  FUNCTION LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    leadEmail VARCHAR2,
    clientId NUMBER
  ) RETURN ResultSetCursor IS
    resultSet ResultSetCursor;
    email VARCHAR2(1000);
    webcastEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    videoEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    documentEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    totalEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    --averageEngagement NUMBER(4,1);
    totalWebcastSeconds NUMBER(10);
    engagementMinutes NUMBER(10, 1);
    last30DaysEM NUMBER(10, 1);
    last60DaysEM NUMBER(10, 1);
    fromDate DATE;
    engagementPrediction NUMBER(10);
  BEGIN...
```

Also, I can't print the result using a `select` statement because the function has DML as well.

Comment: I hope that's not a real e-mail address.:-/

Comment: I changed the e-mail address to a fake one.

Comment: @Gary_W  Had it in mi mind the whole time, but when pasting the code... forgot ¬¬ Thanks jeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't print a cursor like that; it would have to implicitly convert the rows and columns to strings, and that's too much to expect. The `dbms_output.put_line()` procedure only accepts a string argument - or anything that can be implicitly converted to a string. A cursor cannot.

You would have to loop over the cursor result set, fetching into a suitable record type; and then have a `dbms_output` call within that loop which concatenates all the column values from the result set (formatted and possibly padded if you're trying to emulate a select) into a single string.

Without know exactly how `ON24MASTER.WEBCAST_REPORTS.ResultSetCursor` is defined (presumably `TYPE ResultSetCursor IS REF CURSOR`), or what the query that populates it within your procedure is returning - which column names - it's hard to be more specific.

But since you've tagged this for SQL Developer you can use its built-in handling for ref cursor variables, which is handy:

```
variable rc refcursor;

DECLARE
  LEADEMAIL VARCHAR2(200);
  CLIENTID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  LEADEMAIL := 'nunyo@business.com';
  CLIENTID := 22921;

  :rc := WEBCAST_REPORTS.LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    LEADEMAIL => LEADEMAIL,
    CLIENTID => CLIENTID
  );

END;
/

print rc
```

Before the block a bind variable `rc` is declared with [the `variable` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm). Inside the block that is used instead of a local `v_Return`, so that doesn't even need to be declared locally. (Note the colon before `:rc` in the assignment from the function - that denotes a bind variable). And then after the block the client lets you [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm) the ref cursor. (Those doc links are for SQL*Plus, but they are among the [the many commands SQL Developer supports](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer/18.2/rptug/sql-developer-concepts-usage.html#GUID-9C7A6643-E5EC-4505-9294-4AB17F7A0978).)

With a dummy package:

```
create or replace package WEBCAST_REPORTS AS
  TYPE ResultSetCursor IS ref cursor;
  FUNCTION LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    leadEmail VARCHAR2,
    clientId NUMBER
  ) RETURN ResultSetCursor;
end WEBCAST_REPORTS;
/

create or replace package body WEBCAST_REPORTS AS
  FUNCTION LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    leadEmail VARCHAR2,
    clientId NUMBER
  ) RETURN ResultSetCursor IS
    resultSet ResultSetCursor;
  BEGIN
    OPEN resultSet FOR select * from dual;
    RETURN resultSet;
  END LEAD_BASIC_INFO;
end WEBCAST_REPORTS;
/
```

then the code I showed above, run as a script, shows this in the script output window:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


D
-
X
```

Comment: Can't really find where  `ResultSetCursor` is defined. It's not in the package.. where else can I look ?

Comment: Well, I guess that must be a `ref cursor`, but you still need to know what the query is returning to use `dbms_output`. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570362/266304) as a starting point. You might even be able to use the variable/print mechanism if your client supports that - I can't remember off-hand if that work with any ref cursor (I think so...).

Comment: I guess using `set autoprint on;` will do the trick as well with the bind variable. Too bad it is displayed SO HORRIBLE jeje

Comment: @estebanrincon - you can use the normal formatting tools, like `set linesize` and `column x format a10` or whatever, and those are honoured by `print`. Unfortunately `set sqlformat ansiconsole` is not for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle 12c, you can use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`.  I.e.,

```
DECLARE
  LEADEMAIL VARCHAR2(200);
  CLIENTID NUMBER;
  v_Return ON24MASTER.WEBCAST_REPORTS.ResultSetCursor;
BEGIN
  LEADEMAIL := 'nunyo@business.com';
  CLIENTID := 22921;

  v_Return := WEBCAST_REPORTS.LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    LEADEMAIL => LEADEMAIL,
    CLIENTID => CLIENTID
  );

    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_Return); 

END;
```

SQL*Developer will print the results.

Comment: Unfortunately running 11g

Comment: @Matthew I get `ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client.ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2785. ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2779 ` when I tried on 12c in SQL Developer (`Version 4.0.2.15 `). Is this the reason https://www.oraexcel.com/database-oracle-12cR1-ORA-29481#:~:text=Oracle%20Database%20Error%20Code%20ORA%2D29481%20Description&text=Description%3A%20Implicit%20results%20cannot%20be,the%20Oracle%20Database%20Client%20software.

Comment: @SMPH You need to upgrade to a more recent versions of SQL\*Developer.  Version 4.0.x only had the 11.x JDBC drivers embedded in it, iirc.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak What's the best alternative for 12C with above SQL Dev version without defined all the columns? Becuz in my case there are too many columns.

Comment: You don't need to upgrade Oracle.  The feature above works in 12c.  You just need to use more current client software.  Get the latest version of SQL\*Developer and connect it to your existing Oracle database and all should be well.